# jQuery Removing last two characters in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be pretty simple. I'm trying to use the slice method to remove the last two characters in a dynamically created string in a shopping cart.

So instead of having a product show as $28.00, I want the product to show up as $28. Since these values are coming from a database, I can't simply define the string in a variable, like I've seen in a lot of tutorials.

I've created a JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/EbckS/

The jQuery that's not working is below:

```
    $(".myclass").slice(0,-2);
```

Comment: Don't you have to remove the last three to go from "$28.00" to "$28"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `text`.

```
$(".slice").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.slice(0, -2);
});
```

- `i` Reffers the index position of the element in the set
- `text` Reffers the old text value

[Refference](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, this did the trick. I'm new to JS and I was wondering if you could comment on what the (i, text) refers to in the function. Believe it or not that google search was a too basic to find a result :)

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. I uses this for getting number from a string you can use it too.

```
var height= "800px";

var newheight = height.substring(0,height.length-2); //string 800
newheight= parseFloat(newheight) || 0; //number 800
```