# jQuery How to Target A String in a TD Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to subtract a two characters from a string that is being dynamically generated from a database that is being placed into a shopping cart **table  td**.  So instead of having a product show as $28.00, I want the product to show up as $28. Since these values are coming from a database, I can't simply define the string in a variable, like I've seen in a lot of tutorials.

Here's my JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/EbckS/6/

Here's my eronous code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $("table td.SCNProductPrice").text(function(i, text) {
       return text.slice(0, -2);
       });

    });
```

This is a follow up to a different question I posted here:
[jQuery Removing last two characters in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671472/jquery-removing-last-two-characters-in-a-class)

I'm placing this into a different question because I didn't realize targeting a class within a table td would require different syntax. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "dynamically generated" <- is the element present at pageload, or inserted later? Your fiddle is missing a table!

Comment: If the values are coming from a database, can't you process them on the server side?

Comment: Your markup is invalid. http://jsfiddle.net/EbckS/10/

Comment: This seems to be workin http://jsfiddle.net/EbckS/11/

Comment: Have you tried .toFixed(2) instead of .slice?

Comment: If the code shown here is the one you've gotten from the related question, then you should unaccept that answer and add a comment to say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `td` inside a `tr` which is inside a `table`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="SCNProductPrice" valign="top">$28.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EbckS/12/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your html is valid i.e it has table and td your slice has wrong index. First one will take care of any number of decimal points if at all comes up.

try

```
$("table td.SCNProductPrice").text(function(i, text) {
    return '$' + parseInt(text.replace('$',''));
});
```

or

```
 $("table td.SCNProductPrice").text(function(i, text) {
       return text.slice(0, -3);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="SCNProductPrice" valign="top">$28.00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td.SCNProductPrice").text(function(i,text) {
         return text.split('.')[0];
    });
});
```

don't forget, you need valid markup during your fiddle. lastly, i'm not sure why you'd want "$28." shouldn't it just be "$28" ? The JS above does the latter.

Comment: eeek. I apologies on the bad fiddle. That was bad form on my part. I didn't realize that my sloppy html would break. Both of these answers work out. Thanks